# LOOP and nested if statements not working

Tags: vba, excel, loops

the code is intended to seek out the "Yes" in "OverExtensions" and will create a new range and determine the maximum value of the new range. For some reason the logic of the code seems alright but I'm getting an empty result and would love the community's input as to where I've went wrong.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim maximum As Double, OverExtension As Range, x As Range

Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Set OverExtension = Range("D2:D12")
maximum = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("c2:c12"))

For Each x In OverExtension
    If x.Value = Yes Then
        If x.Offset(0, -1).Value = maximum Then
        x.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
        End If
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: On what line is the compile error please?

Comment: As well as `Fratyx` point about the `if` and `for` blocks, this code  `Set OEYes = Union(OEYes, OEResult)` is odd as `OEYES` and `OEResult` are undefined

Comment: It's absolutely useless to say *I get compiler errors* without also including the **specific error** you get and the line you get it on. You have that information right in front of you on the screen, so there's absolutely no reason for you to fail to include it in your question. You're asking us  for **free help** to solve **your problem**; the very least you could do is give us the relevant information that's right in front of your eyes to use to give you that help.

Comment: The compile error states "End If without block If", I apologize for not mentioning it in my post.

Comment: @AlexP The compile error is on "End If" , my apologies

Answer (score 1):

You nested the `if` and `for` blocks in a wrong way.

You have to put the second `End If` between `Next PriceNo` and `Next OEResult`.

Update:

You need just one `End If`. The first one is wrong because `If` and `Then` are in one line.

Besides you have problem with your `OEYes` and `OEResult` variables as they are defined but not initialized but as I don't know your intention I also don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Hi fratyx, I've declared the OEYes and OEResult as Range. My intention is if OEResult.value = "Yes" , a new range will be defined where all the "Yes" values will be stored in a new range "OEYes", which will then find the maximum value of "OEYes"

Comment: In the line `Set OEYes = Union(OEYes, OEResult)` there are no values in the `OEYes` and `OEResult` variables. You have to assign a value to a variable (`Set OEResult = ???`) **before** you can use it on the right side of a `=` operator.

Comment: Hey @Fratyx , I've edited my initial post to a much simpler and cleaner looking code , for some reason the logic seems alright but I'm still getting an empty result.